# Finding the minimum degree of a representation of an algebra

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, representation-theory

I'm reading [this](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1604.06101.pdf) paper, and in it the authors make the following claim (Eq. 27 in the paper):

They first show that a certain subspace of $\mathbb{C}^N$ is invariant under a set of unitary operators $\{Z_i, Y_i\}$, $i=1,...,\alpha$, satisfying

- $[Z_i,Z_j]=0$
- $[Y_i,Y_j]=0$
- $[Y_i,Z_j]=0\quad$ provided $i\neq j$
- $Y_iZ_i=e^{2\pi i p/q}Z_iY_i\qquad$  ($p/q$ is a fraction in lowest form)

They go on to say the algebra generated by the $\{Z_i,Y_i\}$ can be represented in this subspace; in other words, by restricting the $Z_i,Y_i$ to act only on this subspace, we can get a lower-dimensional representation of the algebra. That makes sense. They then say that this representation must have degree at least $q^{\alpha}$, where $q$ is the denominator in the fourth bullet point. I don't understand how they reach this conclusion.

How can we conclude from the relations between the generators that we cannot have a smaller complex representation than degree $q^\alpha$? Is there a method in general to find the minimal degree of a representation from some presentation of an algebra?

Comment: Could you please refer to specific passages in the paper? I can't find those statements there. In particular, I can't find any group mentioned in the context of the $Y_i$ and $Z_i$. The closest I can find to what you write is the left-hand column of page $7$, but that talks about the algebra.

Comment: @joriki you're right, edited. For some reason I thought all you needed was the group structure, but for the last relation to be meaningful it needs to be an algebra representation.

Comment: A good search term is 'quantum torus.'

Comment: @m_t_ That is a good search term, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just listing some observations. Not entirely happy with this yet and not a full solution - I haven't studied the paper, and I need to leave the construction of the representation for later. At this point I will show that the dimension of the representation must be a multiple of $q^\alpha$. If we can then exhibit a representation of minimum dimension $q^\alpha$ we are done.

The point is that corollaries of the given relations force the dimensions of the representations to go up in a manner that is somewhat analogous to the way the commutator relations involving the ladder operators of a simple Lie algebra.

Let's look at a non-trivial representation of this algebra in the case $\alpha=1$.
Assume that $Z_1$ has a non-zero eigenvalue $\lambda$. Let $v$ be an eigenvector
belonging to this eigenvalue. Applying the fourth relation we get 
$$
\lambda Y_1 v= Y_1Z_1v=\zeta Z_1Y_1v, 
$$
where $\zeta=e^{2\pi i p/q}$ is the prescribed root of unity. Rewriting this in the form
$$Z_1(Y_1v)=\zeta^{-1}\lambda (Y_1v)$$
shows that $Y_1v$ is an eigenvector of $Z_1$ belonging to the eigenvalue $\zeta^{-1}\lambda$.

Rinse. Repeat. We see that for all integers $\ell$ the vector $Y_1^\ell v$ is an eigenvector of $Z_1$ belonging to the eigenvalue $\zeta^{-\ell}\lambda$. As $\zeta$ has order $q$ this forces $Z_1$ to have (at least) $q$ distinct eigenvalues. Recall that eigenvectors belonging to different eigenvalues are necessarily linearly independent.
Furthermore (denoting by $V_{\lambda,1}$ the eigenspace of $Z_1$ belonging to eigenvalue $\lambda$):

- By the above argument the action of $Y_1$ maps $V_{\lambda,1}$ injectively into $V_{\zeta^{-1}\lambda,1}$. Injectivity follows from the fact that $Y_1$ is unitary.
- After running through the full circle of eigenvalues we see that we must actually have (assuming a finite dimensional representation) 
  $$\dim V_{\zeta^\ell\lambda,1}=\dim V_{\lambda,1}.$$
- In particular the dimension of the entire representation is a multiple of $q$ (need to check that $q$ is possible).

---

Let's add more generators. When $\alpha=2$ the commutator relations imply that both $Z_2$ and $Y_2$ keep the eigenspaces of $Z_1$ stable. In other words, the eigenspaces $V_{\lambda,1}$ carry a representation of the algebra generated by $Z_2$ and $Y_2$. Repeating the above argument once more shows that the dimensions of all the spaces 
$V_{\zeta^\ell\lambda,1}$ are multiples of $q$. Consequently, in view of the last bullet, the dimension of a representation of the algebra generated by $\{Z_1,Z_2,Y_1,Y_2\}$ is an integer multiple of $q^2$. That integer multiplier being the dimension of a common eigenspace $V_{\lambda,1,\mu,2}$ of $Z_1$ and $Z_2$.
It is hopefully clear that when we add $Z_3$ and $Y_3$, those subspaces $V_{\lambda,1,\mu,2}$ become subrepresentations, and we can keep going.

Comment: Scores of details missing. Sorry about that. Too late an hour here. for me to fix everything. A cleaner argument can probably be made by observing that as the $Z_i$s commute, and act semisimply, we can write the space as a direct sum of their shared eigenspaces. Not unlike splitting a rep of a simple Lie algebra into a sum of shared eigenspaces of a Cartan subalgebra (= the weight spaces). Here those weight spaces must all have the same dimension and orbits of size $q^\alpha$ span submodules etc.

Comment: This is great, thank you! I think it pretty much answers my question, I can fill in the details myself from here (although you are welcome to fill in any details you think are lacking!). For some reason I didn't think about eigenvectors, but this makes sense. As far as constructing a representation with degree exactly $q^\alpha$, it seems pretty easy to define a representation with minimal degree just by specifying what it does to this set of eigenvectors you've defined. But I'll note that the paper is really concerned that it can't be *less* than $q^\alpha$, so I'm happy.

Comment: (I can't yet award the bounty, there's a time limit. But unless someone comes along soon with a proof that is shockingly better I think this answer was rep well spent!)